# Multiple AJAX calls in jQuery each loop causing error when async is true

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous, google-chrome-extension

I am creating a Chrome extension which will add a linked image next to `some_link` on a website. I am using AJAX in order to get a link off of the page which `some_link` links to like so:

```
$( function() {
    $( '#list_of_links li' ).each( function() {
        var refLink = $( this ).find( '.link_id' );
        var some_link = refLink.attr( 'href' );
        var imagesrc = chrome.extension.getURL('image.png');
        var href;
        $.ajax({ 
            url:    some_link,
            success:function( data ) {
                        href = $( data ).find( '#link_i_want' ).attr( 'href' );
                        var linked_image = '<a href="' + href + '"><img src="' + imagesrc + '"></a>';
                        $( linked_image ).insertAfter( refLink );
                    },
            async:  false
        });
    });
});
```

This inserts the images with the correct links for all of the links in the list, but of course hangs the browser until all of the AJAX calls complete. I'm aware that setting `async: true` (or simply removing the `async` setting) will prevent this hanging, but it creates another problem: only *some* of the images are inserted, and jQuery throws the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Your request is already in process. Please click your browser's Refresh/Reload button to continue.
```

In my searches I have not found any mention of this error and I was wondering what caused it and how I can make my code work with `async: true` to speed up page loads and prevent Chrome from hanging.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

### Update:

After looking into the content of the jqXHR objects, I found that some of them were `text/plain` rather than `text/html`, which they should have been. I then looked at what the text was, and found it to be:

> Your request is already in process. Please click your browser's Refresh/Reload button to continue.

What appears to be happening is that the server or Chrome is returning plain text instead of the HTML because I am making too many requests too quickly. Now what I am trying to discover is if there is a way to prevent this from happening.

Comment: are you using the same id several times? `var refLink = $( this ).find( '#link_id' );` ... where does the ajax call get the value of `url` from? (don't see where `link` is defined) ... is your code accurate?, could you post your relevant html? I think you may need to add an index to your `each()` method and place your ajax call in a function and call it from within `each()` passing the index as argument

Comment: Sorry about that, I made some mistakes replacing variables when I was simplifying the example code. That should be a class not an id, and I had `link` previously, which should be `some_link`. I've editted the OP to fix these issues.

Comment: same with `#link_i_want` in the success setting, unless only one id is coming from the response

Comment: That bit is correct; the link I am getting from the other page has its own id.

Comment: Try adding `dataType: "html"` and `cache: false`, see my edited answer

Comment: I tried adding those, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but I would try

```
function ajaxLoop(i) {
    var refLink = jQuery('.link_id').eq(i);
    var some_link = refLink.attr('href');
    var imagesrc[i] = chrome.extension.getURL('image.png');
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: some_link,
        dataType: "html",
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
            href = jQuery(data).find('#link_i_want').attr('href');
            var linked_image = '<a href="' + href + '"><img src="' + imagsrc + '"></a>';
            jQuery(linked_image).insertAfter(refLink);
        }
    });
};

var href, imagesrc = [];

jQuery(function ($) {
    $('#list_of_links li').each(function (i) {
        ajaxLoop(i);
    });
});
```

Comment: or maybe moving the `href` variable inside the function to make it local

Answer (score 0):

Without testing this, what I think your problem is likely to be:

When you are running lock-step, `refLink` will always have the value you want.  But when you go async rip through the loop quicker so `refLink` is changing while you are running your ajax calls.  You need to capture that value for every call.

A potential fix is to put another function in to make the ajax call so that captures the values you need.

Another question is where does `link` get its value?

I'm assuming if you look at the network traffic in your browser's developer tools you'll see all the requests go, but it's the processing going awry.

Comment: After checking the Network Log in Chrome, I can confirm that all of the requests go. When I put the AJAX call into a seperate function, however, it still gives the same error.

Comment: can you post that code?  Or add `console.log` lines to verify that the values of all your variables are what you think they are when the code is being run.